# Obscure fastlane runtime fails. syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end'

Tags: fastlane

My Fastfile lane looked good, but the interpreter reports that it is expecting a matching 'end' (as in do-end pairing).

```
  desc "Test the token passing from Jenkins."
  lane :cliToken do |options|

    token = options[:firebase_cli_token]
    puts "(fastlane) ** Firebase CLI token: #{token}"

    firebase_app_distribution( app:"1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:android:ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
                groups:options[:test_group],
                firebase_cli_token:#{token})
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put the last substitution argument in quotes.

```
        firebase_cli_token:"#{token}")
```

the complete lane-code is:

```
desc "Test the token passing from Jenkins."
  lane :cliToken do |options|

    token = options[:firebase_cli_token]
    puts "(fastlane) ** Firebase CLI token: #{token}"

    firebase_app_distribution( app:"1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:android:ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
                groups:options[:test_group],
                firebase_cli_token:"#{token}")
  end
```

This may be obvious to others, but I lost several hours of head scratching and I did not find anyone with the same solution (although very similar error message).